# Does the song "Na na na na Batman!" exist in the DC comic universe/multiverse?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

In **Batman Vol.7 Issue#.48**, the Joker takes everyone at a church wedding hostage and kills them one-by-one. And just a few moments before Batman arrives at the scene, the Joker is seen casually singing "**na na na na na! Batman!!**" as a sort of welcome song for Batman.

[image]
<sub>*Batman vol.7 issue#48 (page 4)*</sub>

Judging by the lyrics, this is very similar to (or dare I say, the same as) the famous [title track](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Theme) of the 1966 Batman TV series by Neal Hefti starring Adam West.

So, is this some sort of homage to the [1966 TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(TV_series))?

Or does the song "**Na na na na Batman!**" actually exist in the DC comic universe/multiverse?

Comment: The song also appears in _Dark Nights: Metal_ #3 but in a dream sequence.

Comment: If The Lego Batman Movie counts, it's also in that

Comment: Superman movies exist in the DC universe (the actor playing him was named Gregory Reed, which is a clear reference to George Reeves - this was a few years before the first Christopher Reeve film) so it's quite possible there's a Batman TV show, obviously with a fictitious secret identity. Just before the Crisis on Infinite Earths rebooted the DC universe there was a storyline where the villain was a film buff and one of the props he owned was Burgess Meredith's fake nose - presumably he played the Penguin there too.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi3j7HTn-z5AhVLJaYKHYC0AX8QwqsBegQIDBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D3v0sO5lWmp8&usg=AOvVaw1LGGybWNSYJJEbM7xR3Fu9